# Tizen Wearables - Tizen & AngularJS 1.3, Issues with Templating

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I have been experimenting with the Tizen SDK for Wearables and mixing that with AngularJS. We have had good results, great performance and not many complaints with it. Though we do have an issue with the template system in Angular not mixing with how Tizen likes its formats.

We created a template called home.html, using UI Router we gave it a state and everything. Works great and displays.

```
<div class="ui-content">
    <div id="hsectionchangerPage">
        <div id="changer">
            <div>
                <section>
                    Section 1
                </section>
                <section>
                    Section 2
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="/assets/js/lib/section.js"></script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now here is the issue, in Angular (without jQuery) you cannot have that script tag. It will ignore it and not even bother loading it with the templates. So I tried adding jQuery and it does not seem to want to add page listeners to the mix either. It freaks out and does not know what to do with the page for some reason. Has anyone else experienced this issue? Or attempted to do something like this? Please let me know!